# file to XSD_BASE64BINARY in PHP

Tags: php, type-conversion

Actually I am trying with `SOAP` webservice and need converting a `PDF` file to `XSD_BASE64BINARY` type data, I tried using base64_encode() with no success and need something else, some people told me What they did using a "Binary Array" from Java  with  but I couldn't understad clearly What a base64binary data is? and How can generete it from a `PDF` file using `PHP`?. I understand something like convert the file to binary first (`PHP` hasn't function to do that), and then that answer encode with base64_encode(), but I'm not sure. XS

What the correct process is to complete de conversion?

P.D. Sorry by my english, I am mexican and do my best.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: For example, words like a constants codes, or PHP, SOAP or BASE64BINARY, Is the upper case wrong? Which markdown can I use?

Comment: "PHP" and "SOAP" are fine. The W3C website refers to "base64Binary", so I don't think it should be capitalized. When referring to code (constants or otherwise) please use backticks (`\``), e.g. `MY_CONSTANT`. For larger code blocks use the `{}` button to indent your code by four spaces. The part of your title that says "file to" shouldn't have been capitalized; thank you for changing it.